# Group of order 112

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $2^4\times 7$ and Sylow $7$-subgroup of $G$ is not normal. Prove that Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is abelian.

I am very grateful for any help in this problem.

Comment: I wonder though: how does one prove this? (it is correct)